# Jquery targeting different element with shared class

Tags: jquery, html

basically i'm attempting to target elements only within the parent `db_update` div class of the input field that triggers on blur, however it's targeting any class with a matching name, which is not what I want. Ignore the AJAX part as it's irrelevant for now.

I think the problem lies with it targeting the input element on blur, and it's not able to chain to the parent element successfully.

**Basically whichever URL input box i click on is which fields it should fill out, not both.**

http://jsfiddle.net/SXWXu/6/

### HTML

```
<div class="db_update">
<p style="font-size: 12px;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">SLIDE URL: <input type="text" class="slide_URL"  /></span></p>
<div class="status_message"> </div>
<p style="font-size: 12px;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">Slide #: <input type="text" class="slide_num" readonly/></span></p>
<p style="font-size: 12px;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">Document #: <input type="text" class="doc_num" readonly/></span></p>
<p style="font-size: 12px;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">Filter(F): <input type="text" class="filter_num" readonly/></span></p>
</div>

<br/>
<div class="db_update">
<p style="font-size: 12px;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">SLIDE URL: <input type="text" class="slide_URL"  /></span></p>
<div class="status_message"> </div>
<p style="font-size: 12px;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">Slide #: <input type="text" class="slide_num" readonly/></span></p>
<p style="font-size: 12px;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">Document #: <input type="text" class="doc_num" readonly/></span></p>
<p style="font-size: 12px;"><span style="font-weight: normal;">Filter(F): <input type="text" class="filter_num" readonly/></span></p>
</div>
```

### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('input[class=slide_URL]').on({

   blur: function(){
    var status_message = $('.status_message');
    var query_string = encodeURIComponent($(this).val()); 
    var dataString = 'query_string='+ query_string;

     $.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      url: '',
      dataType : 'json',

      data:  dataString ,
      error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {


          $(this).parent().find('.slide_num').val(140);
            $('.doc_num').val(140);
        $('.filter_num').val(140);

      status_message.removeClass().addClass('failure').text('Request was not sent.').show(200);},

      success : function(data) {


       if (data.error === true)
       {


     status_message.show().removeClass('success').addClass('failure').text(data.msg).stop().fadeOut(3000);


     }
    else {
     status_message.show().removeClass('failure').addClass('success').text(data.msg).stop().fadeOut(3000);




         }
     } 
       });    
 return false; 

   }
 });
 });
```

Comment: Why `input[class=slide_URL]` and not `input.slide_URL` ?

Comment: [Keeping your CSS separate](http://jsfiddle.net/SXWXu/19/) makes the HTML much easier to read.  Even if it is just sample code - making things easier on people you are asking for help is never a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the `.db_update` ancestor of the blurred element and then [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the required `status_message`.

```
var status_message = $(this).closest('.db_update').find('.status_message');
```

Comment: my other question then is how come doing `$(this).closest('.db_update').find('input[class=slide_num]').val(140);` does not update the value in the input field to 140

Comment: @Edward `this` in the ajax callback does not refer to the input element, use a variable to store it like `$this` before the ajax call and use it later in the ajax callback function `$this.closest('.db_update').find('input[class=slide_num]').val(140);`

Answer (score 1):

To target only the elements within the same `.db_update` div, starting with an event on one of your `input` elements, you can do this:

```
var status_message = $(this).closest(".db_update").find(".status_message");
```

What that does:

1. Within an event handler on one of your `input` elements, jQuery sets `this` to be a reference to the DOM `input` element.
2. [`$(this)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) creates a jQuery wrapper around that element.
3. [`.closest(".db_update")`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) finds the nearest parent element that matches the selector.
4. [`.find(".status_message")`](http://api.jquery.com/find) finds all of the descendant elements of that element that match the selector.

So breaking it up into its pieces, and assuming `this` is the `input` (which it will be in your event handler):

- `$(this)` - jQuery wrapper around the `input`
- `$(this).closest(".db_update")` - the `.db_session` containing that `input`
- `$(this).closest(".db_update").find(".status_message")` - The `.status_message` elements within that `div`.

Comment: Great answer my other question then is how come doing `$(this).closest('.db_update').find('input[class=slide_num]').val(140);` does not update the value in the input field to 140?

Comment: @Edward: Looks like Musa explained it in the comments under his answer.